# Listview Add Items not appearing C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm working on a small program as part of my A Level Computing course that is designed to track orders.  It is written in C# using the Windows Forms.

I am having an issue where I enter all the information for a new order and then press OK and it should update the ListView with the information.  I have my ListView in Detail view with 4 columns but nothing ever gets added to the ListView.  The section of code that should add the items to the ListView is being executed and is not throwing any errors or causing the program to crash but nothing is being added.  Its weird because I am using the exact same method that I used in my little prototype mock up but for some reason now it is not working.

All the things I've found on here or on the internet seem to suggest its an issue with the View mode of the ListView and I've tried modifying this property to no avail.

Any ideas why this section of code is refusing to add anything to the ListView?

```
            //Create an array to store the data to be added to the listbox
            string[] orderDetails = { Convert.ToString(id + 1), rNameBox.Text, dateBox.Value.ToString(), orderBox.Text };

            //DEBUGGING
            Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[3]);
            //END DEBUGGING

            //Add the order info to the ListView item on the main form
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(orderDetails);
            ths.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

If you need any more information just say.  Apologies if this is in the wrong format or something this is my first time here.

Comment: I would guess it is not adding anything because it fails at compiling? ths -> this.

Comment: It is probably a typo. The OP says that this code runs but doesn't add anything

Comment: Sorry should have explained ths is my link to the form where the ListView resides. I fiddled with it when I was trying to work out what was going on.

Comment: Which made me guess that it is case of "compile error, do you want to use last build?" -> "yes"

Comment: @Steve since VS introduced this idiotic "this did not compile, do you want to run the old version"-MessageBox, the OP might well have just clicked ok on that. I have seen people doing just that and wondering :(

Comment: No it definately compiles and runs with no issues.  Had this issue for a couple of days.  ths is just an example of my terrible naming principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your ListViewItem contains a string array and it has no useful way of displaying it.

What you should be doing (there are a number of ways of doing this, but here's one) is creating a class, OrderDetail, with an Id, a Name, a Date, and so on. Give it a ToString() method (public override string ToString()) which returns what you want to display, e.g.:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

Create an instance of OrderDetail and set its properties. Create ListViewItem giving it the OrderDetail instance and add to the ListView. Repeat for as many OrderDetail instances you want.

Cheers -

Added: code which works:

```
    int id = 12;
    string rNameBoxText = "rName";
    DateTime dateBoxValue = DateTime.Now;
    string orderBoxText = "order";
    string[] orderDetails = { Convert.ToString(id + 1), rNameBoxText, dateBoxValue.ToString(), orderBoxText };

    //DEBUGGING
    Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(orderDetails[3]);
    //END DEBUGGING

    this.listView1.Columns.Clear();
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Id");
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("rName");
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Date");
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Order");
    this.listView1.View = View.Details;
    //Add the order info to the ListView item on the main form
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(orderDetails);
    this.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

Comment: But I did it this way before and a string array is one of the options displayed by intellisense.  The idea of the string array is that it holds one item for each column

Comment: Ah ha! In that case you have to set up the ListView to be columnar: the default is to have one column per row. You need to edit the Columns property of the ListView.

Comment: I already have my ListView set up with 4 columns as I thought I would need but it still isn't working. Its confusing because I have already done this once in a prototype thing and I'm doing it the exact same way and its not working :/

Comment: Long time since I did this, however... Have you changed the View property to Details?

Comment: I have indeed set it to details.  I think it says that in OP

Comment: OK. I've added code in the answer above which works for me. (I didn't add the text boxes, just set up strigs, int and date). If you copy that, does it work?

Comment: PS This code is in the form load event. Where is the code in your example?

Comment: So the ListView is on Form1.  This code is being executed on the OnClick Event of a button on a NewOrder form.  The ths I had referenced was a parameter I was taking as a constructor that referenced Form1 so that I could access the ListView.  I set the columns in design view but I also just tried this method and that didn't work either.  Its not even clearing the columns so it must be an issue with the way I am accessing the ListView.  I'll do some more research and come back to you.

Comment: Well, that's...novel. Usually, only the form that owns a control would change that control; by default controls are private and can only be changed by code within the owning form. Presumably you've made listView1 public? Why have you chosen this design? The usual way of doing this would be to have NewOrder expose an event with a new EventArgs type which carried the orderDetails data. NewOrder would raise this event at the appropriate time. Form1 would subscribe to this event of NewOrder, and in the event handler would take the data from the EventArgs and change nits ListView as required.

Comment: I feel like an idiot..... One static in the wrong place and the whole thing goes kaput.  I apologise for wasting your time.  That method does however sound much better and more efficient so I know what I'm reading tomorrow.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No problem what-so-ever! If I'd asked better questions earlier we'd have got there sooner; but we got there.